# Getting spring season in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I'm trying to getting spring season in SQL Server.

Query I wrote is about getting all clients have got most bill amount during spring. Doesn't mind year. I want to do something like this:

```
select  
    c.clientId, c.name,
    b.billId, b.date,
    sum(b.total) as total
from 
    Client c 
join 
    Bill b on c.clientId = b.clientId
where 
    month(b.date) between 09 and 12 --when month is 09
      -- saying day(b.date) is 
      --same or greater than 21
       -- and when month is 12
        -- day(b.date) is same
         -- or less than 21
group by 
    c.clientId, c.name, b.billId, b.date, b.total 
order by
    total desc
```

Whether in 2019 should be same or greater than '20190921 00:00:00.000' and same or less than '20191221 23:59:59.000' considering structure of my query.

Anyone can have solution?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: I'm using sql server.

Comment: Does this query REALLY do what you want? If you include b.billId in your group by clause, i'm guessing that your sum doesn't actually do anything useful. The inclusion of b.date seems to be logical flaw as well.

Comment: And if your table contains bills from different years (and your business probably DOES want to see that happen), is your query still correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
where
    b.date >= datefromparts(year(b.date), 9, 21)
    and b.date < datefromparts(year(b.date), 12, 21)
```

In your query:

```
select  
    c.clientId, 
    c.name,
    sum(b.total) as total
fromcClient c 
inner join bill b on c.clientId = b.clientId
where
    b.date >= datefromparts(year(b.date), 9, 21)
    and b.date < datefromparts(year(b.date), 12, 21)
group by c.clientId, c.name
order by total desc
```

Note that I fixed the `group by` clause so it groups rows per customer (you had unwant additional columns in that clause, especially `date`).

Unrelad : September 21st to December 21st is Fall, not Spring. If you wanted Spring, then:

```
where
    b.date >= datefromparts(year(b.date), 3, 21)
    and b.date < datefromparts(year(b.date), 6, 21)
```